# How to show $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges to the same limit $\sqrt 2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_1=2$ and $b_1=1$ and for $n \geq 1$ , $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n+b_n}{2},  b_{n+1}=\dfrac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}$.Show that the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges to the same limit $\sqrt 2$.

trial: Let $a_n$ converges to $a$ and $b_n$ converges to $b$. So I get $a=\dfrac{a+b}{2},  b=\dfrac{2ab}{a+b}$ and $a=b$ But how I show $a=b=\sqrt2$

Comment: $a_nb_n=$? $ $ $ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that $$a_{n+1} \geq b_{n+1} \,\,\,\,\,\, (\text{Since Arithmetic mean is greater than the Harmonic mean})$$
Further,
$$a_{n+1} - b_{n+1} = \dfrac{(a_n-b_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)}$$
Now since $2 \geq a_n>b_n \geq 1$, we have $a_n + b_n > 2$ and hence
$$a_{n+1} - b_{n+1} = \dfrac{(a_n-b_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)} < \dfrac{(a_n-b_n)^2}4 < \dfrac{(a_1-b_1)^2}{4^{2n-1}} = \dfrac1{4^{2n-1}} \,\,\,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$
Hence, since $a_n$ is a bounded monotone decreasing sequence and $b_n$ is a bounded monotone increasing sequence both converge and from $ (\spadesuit)$, we get that
$$a_n \to b_n$$Further,
$$a_{n+1} b_{n+1} = a_nb_n$$ and hence $$a_n b_n = a_1 b_1 = 2$$
Hence, conclude that both should converge to $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}$ is $1$ when $n\to \infty$ to see that they are asymptotically convergent.

Comment: Nice observation!+1

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Show first that $a_nb_n=2$ for all $n$. Then show that $a_n>a_{n+1}>b_{n+1}>b_n$ for all $n$. The [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) may be helpful.